# Assigning functions to events in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the onchange event for a dropdown list.
I've been doing some reading and found that the preferred way to handle the change event is:

```
select.onchange = function(){animateMarker()};
```

I was just wondering why it couldn't just be:

```
select.onchange = animateMarker();
```

What is the function() preceding animateMarker() doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign onclick event to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740761/assign-onclick-event-to-function)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
select.onchange = animateMarker;
```

Adding the `()` executes the function immediately, removing them means that you're assigning the function to the event handler, so that it will be executed eventually.

And to answer the last part: the function () {} that wraps animateMarker is unnecessary, it is simply an anonymous function that executes the `animateMarker` function when it is called.

Comment: *"..., removing them means –"* – that you're assigning the function to the event handler, so that it will be executed eventually. That's probably a better way to put that.

Answer (score 0):

As @mrwillihog said you can assign it directly with it's definition like `select.onchange = animateMarker;` however it's wise to use a wrapper function as advised since by doing so you may add more functions later to the `onchange` event by inserting into the wrapper function. Otherwise you will be limited with only `animateMarker` event... or... you might need to redefine the animateMarker and do some ugly monkey patches. So it's best to use a wrapper function.

Comment: 1) If and when you want to add more event listeners, you can add a function wrapper then. 2) You should be using `addEventListener` anyway instead of directly overwriting the event handler property exactly for that reason.